# Facebook Raffle won by organiser's spouse

Tags: united-kingdom, gambling, social-media

I recently joined a UK based Facebook group which the owner/admin uses to run raffles to raise money for a youth football team. I believe this doesn't require a licence as it is to raise funds for a good cause.

One of the first posts I saw on it was to state that a raffle for an iMac had been won by the organiser's husband, which makes me cringe slightly. Does this make it unlawful because it could be argued that spouses have joint ownership, and therefore this would be personal gain?

Comment: Are we assuming, for this question, that the raffle was entire fair?

Comment: we don't know the details of the raffle, we don't know the rules that govern participation.

Comment: I'm only interested in whether it is lawful for the described scenario, regardless of any other rules. I have no way of knowing whether it was conducted fairly or not.

Comment: It seems that the question is: Under UK law, if a raffle is conducted under an exception for charitable purposes, is there a law prohibiting participation in the raffle by the organizer, organizer's spouse, or anyone else?  (Notes: I am assuming such an exception exists because the OP said as much. Also, I said UK law understanding that laws might vary in different parts of the UK. I was just trying to clarify the legal question),

Comment: @Damila Yes that would be a good clarification. And good point about different countries of the UK having different laws: in this case the jurisdiction is England and Wales.

Comment: Not a full answer, but some pertinent info:  it appears this would be a [small society lottery](https://www.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/for-the-public/Fundraising-and-promotions/Fundraising/Small-society-lotteries.aspx) in the terminology of the Gambling Commission.  The rules surrounding such lotteries on the Gambling Commission's website don't seem to have any rules about who can win;  but such lotteries have to be registered with local licensing authorities, and I don't know whether those authorities would impose additional rules.